# Color numbers differently in emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to color numbers differently from the text characters in emacs for any mode that emacs is in. How do I modify the .emacs file for this purpose? I would like my numbers 
to always show up in pink.

Gvim seems to have this feature built in already.

Comment: It is late at night here where I am and I've only tested this one time:  `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (font-lock-add-keywords nil (list (list "\\([0-9]+\\)" '(0 font-lock-warning-face t)) ))))`  That should put you in the right direction -- the hook is for the major mode `text-mode`.  You can adjust the regexp as needed.

Comment: There's a *highlight-numbers* mode on melpa and also available [here](https://github.com/Fanael/highlight-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Usage -- activate or deactivate **locally** with:   `M-x smilingbuddha-mode`

To enable `smilingbuddha-mode` **globally**, either uncomment `(global-smilingbuddha-mode)` and restart; or, type `M-x global-smilingbuddha-mode` (which will remain in effect until you restart).

Please feel free to modify the regexp to suit your personal needs.

```lisp
(define-minor-mode smilingbuddha-mode
  "Minor mode for highlighting numbers."
  :group 'smilingbuddha
  :lighter " :)"
  (cond
    (smilingbuddha-mode
      (when (not (or font-lock-mode global-font-lock-mode))
        (font-lock-mode 1))
      (font-lock-add-keywords nil
        (list (list "\\([0-9]+\\)" '(0 'smilingbuddha-pink-face t)) ))
      (message "Turned ON `smilingbuddha-mode`."))
    ((not smilingbuddha-mode)
      (font-lock-remove-keywords nil
        (list (list "\\([0-9]+\\)" '(0 'smilingbuddha-pink-face t)) ))
      (font-lock-fontify-buffer)
      (message "Turned OFF `smilingbuddha-mode`."))))

(defgroup smilingbuddha nil
  "Highlight numbers."
  :version "0.1"
  :group 'smilingbuddha)

(defface smilingbuddha-pink-face
  '((t (:foreground "black" :background "pink")))
  "Face for `smilingbuddha-pink-face`."
  :group 'smilingbuddha)

(defun turn-on-smilingbuddha-mode ()
(interactive)
  (smilingbuddha-mode 1))

(defun turn-off-smilingbuddha-mode ()
(interactive)
  (smilingbuddha-mode -1))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-smilingbuddha-mode
  smilingbuddha-mode turn-on-smilingbuddha-mode)
;; (global-smilingbuddha-mode)
```